# How to connect more to the community?

Tags: blockchain

We are honored to share with you our conceptual artwork of $XMR It's aspect ratio is 16:9 so you can use it as wallpaper for your smartphones. Using it is not prohibited by law and we would be happy if our artwork is used by people who appreciate it. We were wondering how we could share our artwork with as many members of the community as possible, so could really use your help towards this goal of ours.

[image]